# How I can get average number from array without using array_sum or any other function?

Tags: php, arrays

I had a task to write program that gives 20 numbers from 9 to 99 using empty array and rand function which I did...but the second step is for me to calculate and get the average number.

With functions like array_sum I can get what I want, but the idea is not to use any of array functions, just arithmetic operators

```
$arrNums = array();
$sum = 0;
$intTotalNum = 20;

for($i = 0; $i < $intTotalNum; $i++) {
  $intRand = rand(9, 99);
  $arrNums[] = $intRand;
  $sum = $sum + $arrNums;
  $average = $sum / count($arrNums);
}


var_dump($arrNums);
echo "<br>";
echo $average;
```

Code gives me an error "Unsupported operand types"

Comment: you are trying add a integer with an array that's why the error "Unsupported operand types"

Comment: So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can achieve it without using an array functions:

```
$arrNums = array();
$sum = 0;
$intTotalNum = 20;

for($i = 0; $i < $intTotalNum; $i++) 
{
  $intRand = rand(9, 99);
  array_push($arrNums,$intRand);
  $sum = $sum+$intRand;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrNums);
echo "<br>";
echo $sum;


//echo $average;
```

Just add your `$sum` to current `$intRand` and print it outside the loop.

The reason why I have used `array_push` functions so that you can print all the array elements outside for loop and check and verify how many numbers generated. If you don't want to print an array then it is no need, you can comment or remove it.

Comment: ```array_push``` is a array function !

Comment: Updated! I have just used to push elements for debugging purpose, I am not manipulating any array functions to get sum :) @shihab

Answer (score 1):

Just put the $average out side the for loop

```
    $arrNums = array();
    $sum = 0;
    $intTotalNum = 20;

    for($i = 0; $i < $intTotalNum; $i++) {
      $intRand = rand(9, 99);
      $arrNums[] = $intRand;
      $sum += $intRand;

    }

    $average = $sum / $intTotalNum;

    var_dump($arrNums);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $average;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying add a integer with an array that's why the error "Unsupported operand types" . you can get the average more easily like this

```
    $sum = 0;
    $intTotalNum = 20;
    $arrNums = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $intTotalNum; $i++) {
      $arrNums[] = rand(9, 99);
      $sum = $sum + $arrNums[$i];
    }

    $average = $sum / $intTotalNum;
    var_dump($arrNums);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $average;
```

Comment: Can you explain me why we need variable $intSum with value of 0, and how that affects on code to give us average number?

Comment: we are initializing $sum with 0  so that we can add other values into it . like it is a basket before you put anything on it you have to empty it . so that it remains with only the things that you have put into it

Comment: It's a complete waste to calculate the average on each iteration.

Comment: @Andreas you are right .i have updated my code . At first i just pointed the fault in his code